# Updating and persisting claims across separate applications with Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have two applications (one ASP.NET Core and one Blazor WASM) using the same Identity Server based service to log users in. Users need to be able to move seamlessly (or as seamlessly as possible) between these two applications - i.e. it needs to look like one app (we are having to do it this way for historic reasons, eventually we hope to move everything to Blazor).

Once authenticated, users have several claims added against them including the ID of the school they belong to. Most of these claims will remain unchanged throughout the user's session, however I need to implement a feature for admins that allows them to switch between schools on the system and therefore I need to be able to update their school ID claim.

Currently claims are configured separately by both applications by doing checks against the database after the user has been authenticated, but I don't think this is going to work for us anymore because any temporarily updated claims such as school ID will not then be persisted between the two applications. To be clear, when a user switches to another school I do not want that to be a permanent change - i.e. as soon as they log out and back in again they should be logged in to their original school, not the school they switched to.

I think I've figured out how to set the claims in the Identity Server project instead of within each app separately, but how do I then update that claim if a user switches schools in one app or the other? Or am I approaching this in totally the wrong way?